# Cannot get my Chart to bind to my database in C#.net

Tags: c#, database, data-binding, charts

I am a complete newby at this, but I am trying to make a chart in Windows Forms that will accept data from a compactSQL database I set up.  My application is able to enter data into the database okay, but now I want to bind that data to the x axis of a chart.  I tried using just the visual tools, and the chart properties to do this, but all I get is a red X where my chart should be.  I have now gone to some sample charts and tried to code my chart using the databinding.  Below is what I have got so far.  Again, I am completely new to this, so I don't even fully understand what some of this is doing.

When I run this code, it gives me an unhandled exception at the "myReader" line.  It says this, "There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 24,Token in error = Database ]"

Any thoughts on what I am missing, or what is wrong with my code here?

```
        string dataFile = @"Test\Database1.sdf";

        string myConnectionString = @"Data Source=C:\Users\zfam\My   Projects\programming\visual studio\Database Test\Database " + dataFile;


        string mySelectQuery = "SELECT test3 FROM Test Database";

        SqlCeConnection myConnection = new SqlCeConnection(myConnectionString);


        SqlCeCommand myCommand = new SqlCeCommand(mySelectQuery, myConnection);

        myCommand.Connection.Open();


        MessageBox.Show(myConnection.State.ToString());
        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();


        SqlCeDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);


        chart1.Series["Default"].Points.DataBindXY(myReader, "test3");


        myReader.Close();
        myConnection.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to rewrite the query as:

```
string mySelectQuery = "SELECT test3 FROM Test";
```

Comment: That gives me a "The specified table does not exist. [ Test ]"